# vb.net word application interop object error

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net to create word documents, i have this code:

```
Imports word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Dim oWord As New word.Application
Dim oDoc As word.Document
oWord.Visible = global_variables.ShowWordDocs
```

but when running, i am getting this error on the last line:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-
0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

The value of the last line equals `False`

i have tried repairing Microsoft Office - all i have installed is word, excel, office shared features and office tools - version 2010

Answer (score 0):

Error implies that there's an issue with the COM interface.  Have you tried re-registering (RegSvr32.exe /i ...) the COM DLLs/TLBs/OLBs for Word/Excel?  These will be in your Office installation folder (e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14)